# Arkit: Editing a Scene file (.scn)

Tags: xcode, scenekit, arkit

I have Arkit sample code that I've compiled and it works great. I'd like to know if there's any way I can edit one of the included .scn files to inscribe text on the object. Perhaps within Xcode or another tool?

Comment: Xcode edits .scn files, and your post is off-topic, have a nice day!